# Visual Studio 2015 database(.mdf) versioning

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently developing a project in C# using Visual Studio 2015 with a database but I can't get it to commit with built-in Git Source Control. I did some research and found out that I shouldn't try to commit .mdf files but make a script so the database creates automatically. Unfortunately I can't find this option anywhere. What can I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Visual Studio Database project.

In Visual Studio you can simply connect to your database, right click on it and say "Create New Project". That will allow you to import your database into Database Project. Database project is basically a bunch of SQL scripts for all your database objects. You can add that project into source control. After that you make changes to your database by modifying items in your database projects. You commit these changes to source control the same way you would do with any other VS project. Even if you made changes to your database outside VS, using Management Studio, for example, you can still sync your project with the database and commit detected changes to source control.

Comment: Can you write some more details please? I should make a new project, a new database in it and ilnk i to my project or use my existing database in that database project? And then i should make a script to generate the database in this project and add it to my version control?

Comment: ^^ Added some details to the answer