# Github check in local database

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, along with the Github plugin.

For a assignment I have to use C# with a database, which isn't a problem within VS. But, I want to check the local database into the repository, so I can work on the project on multiple computers.

**I'm the only one who will use this repository** (it's private). There won't be  changes apart from my own.

I know it's not really meant to do this, but I really would like to remain working with local databases for simplicity purposes.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35160654/7193940) answer on the topic, but I'm not sure what he's trying to say.

Comment: I am confused to get your question . I think you should have commented on a question related to your issue ?

Comment: I was afraid that I wasn't clear enough. Let me try again. I use a git to versioncontrol my application. But, you can't (by default) sync databases. I'm looking for a way to get my local database to sync with git via the Visual Studio plugin.

Comment: I do really thank you for asking such a beautiful question that opened my mind . And I found this blog and it really explains how to do this job . And I realized that I will be needing this :) . Please check out the link [ http://ben.kulbertis.org/2011/10/synchronizing-a-mysql-database-with-git-and-git-hooks/ ]

Comment: Thank you! That sounds like the way to go! I'll give this a try tomorrow (in about 12 hours :)) Can you post this as a answer? If it works I can give it the fancy green checkmark :)

Comment: Okay, I couldn't help myself but to have a quick peek at it. In the `hooks` folder there is only a `readme.sample` file, and no subdirectories. I can't make up from the help doc if I should be making the folder myself? How am I supposed to put the script in? (Only used the GUI if you didn't notice already :p)

Comment: Oh, derp. Maybe I should just look it up before starting to ask questions :s I'm having a problem tho; since I'm using VS to generate the database for me, how am I supposed to get a MySQL user out of VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do really thank you for asking such a beautiful question that opened my mind . And I found this blog and it really explains how to do this job . And I realized that I will be needing this :) . Please check out the [synchronizing-a-mysql-database-with-git-and-git-hooks](http://ben.kulbertis.org/2011/10/synchronizing-a-mysql-database-with-git-and-git-hooks/)   Hope this helps .

Comment: So I'm using VS2017 as suggested by jessehouwing. I've been trying for the past 1,5 hours to get this working, but it's failing. Obviously I have no idea what I'm doing :p. The Github windows software is kind enough to give me a error (which VS doesn't btw), but I'm not sure where to look next... I get `GitHub.IO.ProcessException: .git/hooks/pre-commit: line 2: mysqldump: command not found` Also, where am I supposed to get the MySQL user and pass from?

Answer (score 1):

When you use Visual Studio together with SQL Server Developer tools you can have your database schema and initial data scripted out as a Visual Studio project. You'd then use the Visual Studio project to define what the database looks like and you can then use the project to create a SQL Server LocalDB or SQL Server Express database on demand when you restore your project. You can sync the schema between your local database and the Visual Studio project. And commit the difference to git.

Alternatively you could use something like Entity Framework to define your database schema or use Entity Framework Code First annotations to map your object model to a database schema. Combined with Entity Framework Migrations and Entity Framework Data Initializers you can instruct you application to rebuild the database at startup time should it be missing.

Using Git pre-commit hooks on Windows is not the easiest thing to setup and Visual Studio 2012-2015 won't execute your hooks, you'd have to do all your git operations through the commandline for these hooks to start working. Visual Studio 2017 uses the git.exe commandline tool and should be able to run your hooks, though support for hooks is still limited if you're using a normal command shell instead of a bash shell (linux shell). Most hooks are implemented as Linux shell scripts or other scripting languages that are not always fully supported on Windows.

Depending on the file size, you could always just commit the database file itself, the binary files. Though git generally doesn't like binaries, nothing prevents you from committing the latest state and transferring it to another machine this way.

Comment: As one who isn't experienced in databases, what would be the easiest way to achieve my goal? The database file isn't that big right now, but I want to store a lot of small bits of data in it (timings), so maybe that could become an issue further down the line?   If all of this gets too complicated I'll just have to look at how to use a MySQL server (my school provides a host, but I can host it myself if that's necessary)...

Comment: You mention that VS2017 (which I am using for my private projects to get familiar) can use git hooks, but I can't find anything about this on the internet. Do you have a source for this?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 uses git.exe to talk to your repo and no longer relies on LibGit2, it should now support anything the normal git.exe can do on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I usually but the instructions to build the database into the repository, either a .sql file or a script to execute the commands needed to restore the database.

A database like sqlite is stored in only one file, that you could easily put in your git repository.

If your looking for more concrete ideas, you might want to share what database your working with.

Comment: Ah, I didn't mention what database I'm using! Whoops :) It's a MySQL database. I think I have the answer from the comment @katmancho made, but I still need to give it a try :)