# Check in Local SQL Server Database from Visual Studio into GitHub repository

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, github

I found this question/answer here, but it's not quite what I'm looking for:

[Github check in local database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41046802/github-check-in-local-database)

What I'm trying to do is as follows:

I want to create a .NET Core project using Entity Framework Core. But what I want to be able to do is check in the "local" database *along with* my project, so I can work on it between different computers.

So to be clear, I want to take the database referenced in appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"MyContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyContext-ec5bc257-ecdd-4ba2-b576-4177dce77300;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",}
```

And check it into my repository, so that I can go to a different computer, pull down the full solution, and get the database as well.

Perhaps the question/answer above does answer my question and I just don't realize it because of my lack of familiarity with Github.

I'm not all that familiar with GitHub, and all of my searches have come up empty. Maybe I'm not searching for the right stuff. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can do that if your database is in the form of a [database project](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssdt/how-to-create-a-new-database-project) and you mark it as a dependency of your EF project; on build you can have the DB automatically deploy to LocalDB. Alternatively, if your EF project uses a model-first approach then the application can have EF create the database on start. Neither of these approaches will preserve data, however; if you want that you should script it out (or host your DB instance in the cloud as an Azure SQL instance, for example).

Comment: Thanks, @JeroenMostert. I will give that a shot and report back. If it works, I'll accept your response as the answer!